# Is it possible for someone to make a purposefully vulnerable site then take advantage of that vulnerability to hack the users?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability

Is it possible for someone to make a purposefully vulnerable site then lure users to his site where he then takes advantage of that vulnerability to hack their social media accounts etc? If so how?

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172582/do-drive-by-attacks-exist-in-modern-browsers

Comment: Here's a takeaway: "..Is it possible for someone to make a purposefully vulnerable site then take advantage of that vulnerability to hack the users?.." Yes.

Comment: @CriticalSYS How tho?

Comment: Although not directly, the owner can place a hook on his site, where after he takes advantage of different known methods such as drive-by downloads like @mti2935 said, reverse shells, etc.

Comment: what about something like stealing cookies can you do that @CriticalSYS?

Comment: Fundamentally that's what a **Honeypot** is, but the users are generally malicious actors.

Comment: A second example would be that a reputable team behind a website replaces It's updates/software with a trojan or more disastrously that a server fetches and installs that "legitimate software" from that site automatically.

Comment: I don't think the site would be vulnerable, but rather malicious in nature.

Comment: It's not a honeypot, but an exploit kit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for someone to make a purposefully vulnerable site

Yes.

> then take advantage of that vulnerability to hack the users?

Yes but, he doesn't need the vulnerability.

When we talk about a vulnerable site, that usually means it allows anyone to do some action which was not intended by the owner. For example, a vulnerable StackOverflow site could allow anyone to log in under the account of someone else. However, if I was the owner of StackOverflow and wanted to take over your account I wouldn't need to exploit a vulnerability on the page. I could do that directly (such as manually changing your password to something else).

The main reason I can think for that would be for plausible deniability / looking inept rather than malicious.

Comment: What about if there was no user interaction any farther than simply opening the website ?

Comment: @mohamedelgamal and the website would be vulnerable in what sense? I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: like it would be vulnerable to some sort of web app vuln that would allow it to hack its users social media/work/personal accounts on the users laptop. For example something that would allow it to steal cookies. That is just an example tho.

Comment: The app doesn't need to be vulnerable. It can already see its own cookies. You might be thinking on stealing cookies of a different website, but it's not the that would need to be vulnerable, but the user browser which is not supposed to give your Gmail cookies to  StackOverflow.